# Excel: How to automatically use formulas without = sign

Tags: excel, vba

I thought this was cool when I figured it out and would share.

The code removes the need to add "=" signs in front of formulas. This can give your excel sheet more of a software feel when creating templates designed for calculations to be made frequently.

In my case I have a financial analysis template that requires you have to add many items together in many different cells and much of our other templates are not excel based and do not require the "=" which causes aggravation for users switching between the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Trigger Macro
If Target.Cells.Count > 0 Then

'Define Variables
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As String

Set rng = Target

'Add equal sign to all updated cells
On Error GoTo NoFormulas
    If rng = "" Then
    Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
        ElseIf rng = Range("C2") Then
        Exit Sub
            Else
                For Each cell In rng
                On Error GoTo NoFormulas
                x = cell.Formula
                cell = "=" & Right(x, Len(x))
                On Error GoTo 0

                Next cell
                Exit Sub

    End If


End If

'Error Handler
NoFormulas:
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```